# F1 teams to win their first grand prix

Tags: formula-1

I saw a social media post which claimed

> Brawn GP is one of just four teams to have won their very first race.

I presume one of the other three teams is Alfa Romeo, who won the first ever official F1 grand prix. I have also found out that Mercedes won their first F1 race, in 1954, at the hands of Fangio.

Who is the final team?

Comment: Brawn was in fact the old Honda team - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brawn_GP

Comment: @davidjwest indeed - Brawn was formerly Honda, which was formerly BAR, which was formerly Tyrrell. So the "new" Brawn team actually had a continuous F1 heritage of nearly 40 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be Wolf, at the 1977 Argentine Grand Prix. I admit I had to Google to confirm my guess.

[Source](http://en.f1i.com/magazine/86525-f1-teams-won-gp-debuts.html/3)